# Is it normal for 1000 threads to launch on booting up MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, macos

My MacBook Pro is very slow immediately after booting up. Only after 5-6 mins have passed after booting, I am able to launch any application or use my MacBook properly. When I checked processes using "top" command on mac Terminal, I saw almost 1000 threads running on my MacBook. Is this normal ?
Attaching the screenshot of "top" command.

```
 Processes: 302 total, 2 running, 300 sleeping, 1020 threads                                                                                  23:19:55
Load Avg: 1.58, 1.58, 1.52  CPU usage: 9.48% user, 5.59% sys, 84.91% idle    SharedLibs: 253M resident, 63M data, 23M linkedit.
MemRegions: 26938 total, 1140M resident, 158M private, 304M shared. PhysMem: 3526M used (1011M wired), 569M unused.
VM: 1759G vsize, 1118M framework vsize, 320(0) swapins, 320(0) swapouts. Networks: packets: 51990/48M in, 45361/7234K out.
Disks: 157047/5111M read, 51916/1058M written.

PID  COMMAND      %CPU  TIME     #TH   #WQ  #PORT MEM    PURG   CMPRS  PGRP PPID STATE    BOOSTS           %CPU_ME %CPU_OTHRS UID  FAULTS   COW
720  SandboxedSer 0.0   00:00.03 2     1    47    1364K  12K    0B     720  1    sleeping  0[1]            0.00000 0.00000    501  3142     178
719  ocspd        0.0   00:00.02 2     1    30    1176K  0B     0B     719  1    sleeping *0[1]            0.00000 0.00000    0    1785     139
718  syspolicyd   0.0   00:00.09 2     1    33    3432K  44K    0B     718  1    sleeping  0[1]            0.00000 0.00000    0    3640     178
717  XprotectServ 0.0   00:00.05 2     2    44    3032K  0B     0B     717  1    sleeping  0[1]            0.00000 0.00000    501  3673     177
715  QuickLookSat 0.0   00:00.68 2     1    53    13M    1856K  0B     715  1    sleeping  0[0]            0.00000 0.00000    501  17221    246
713  automountd   0.0   00:00.02 7     1    30    1144K  0B     0B     713  1    sleeping *0[1]            0.00000 0.00000    0    2619     187
712  com.apple.ap 0.0   00:00.73 4     2    210+  9776K+ 12K    0B     712  1    sleeping *0[21+]          0.00000 0.03544    501  10239+   377
711  cupsd        0.0   00:00.08 3     1    45    2676K  0B     0B     711  1    sleeping  0[0]            0.00000 0.00000    0    2327     152
710  printtool    0.0   00:00.04 2     2    31    1056K  0B     0B     710  1    sleeping  0[27]           0.00000 0.00000    501  2618     159
708  colorsync.us 0.0   00:00.03 2     1    51    1012K  0B     0B     708  1    sleeping *0[1]            0.00000 0.00000    501  1665     146
707  MTLCompilerS 0.0   00:00.42 2     2    32    21M    0B     0B     707  1    sleeping  0[13]           0.00000 0.00000    501  9832     257
706  MTLCompilerS 0.0   00:00.15 2     2    25    6312K  0B     0B     706  1    sleeping  0[3]            0.00000 0.00000    0    5070     253
705  com.apple.hi 0.0   00:00.06 2     2    33    996K   0B     0B     705  1    sleeping  0[80]           0.00000 0.00000    501  1679
```

As far as I remember on Linux laptops, number of threads launched immediately after boot up is far fewer when compared to macOS.

Comment: On boot, my Mac Mini (mid-2011) High Sierra with a 3rd party SSD has upwards of 1700 - 1800 threads running. With nothing but the browser I'm using to type this, Terminal (to see the results of `top`,) and a Time Machine backup running, the Mini is now at 1187 threads. I also have Dropbox, Google Drive and other background processes running. Time Machine finished, and now down to 1112 threads. The bigger problems is that you have to wait 5-6 minutes until your MBP is usable is odd. What specific model of MBP and which macOS is running?

Comment: @IconDaemon - i am using MacBook Pro(13 inch, Mid-2012) and macOS High Sierra version 10.13.4

Answer (score 1):

The number of processes doesn't really matter, as long as they don't consume CPU time. Rerun with `top -o cpu` to see the processes using most CPU at the top.

Having said that,

- right now you have 302 active processes which looks okish for a freshly booted system
- a load average of 1.58/1.58/1.52 is practically nothing, and the CPU is 84.9% idle.

So whatever slowness you experience does not come from anything CPU intensive.